# Finding records with duplicated keys

Tags: text-processing

I have multiple gzip-compressed files with millions of lines in a single file. Generally, there are numbers that have one `assocId` and one `IMPI`, `IMPU`, and `MSISDN` attached to it.

```
assoc=1
IMPI=XXX
IMPU=YYY
MSISDN=ZZZ
IMSI=PPP
```

But there are occurrences where one `assocId` may have multiple `IMPI`, `IMPU`, `IMSI` and `MSISDN`, like below:

```
assocId=2
IMPI=ddd
IMPI=eee
IMPU=fff
IMPU=ggg
IMSI=hhh
IMSI=iii
MSISDN=jjj
MSISDN=kkk
```

I want to list all those occurrences of `assocId` with multiple `IMPI`, `IMPU`, `IMSI` and `MSISDN` attached.

One `assocId` can have multiple 1, 2 or more `IMPI`, `IMPU`, `IMSI` and `MSISDN` associated with it.

Please suggest.

Comment: What have you researched and tried on your own?

Comment: Wasn't able to try much since I know only about grep and its just giving me the occurence. I am not able to list all those assocId with multiple IMPi IMPU combinations

Comment: Your first example uses `assoc` instead of `assocId`.  Also, is there a blank line between each record, or do they occur directly after each other?

Answer (score 1):

I created the test source file:

```
assocId=1
IMPI=XXX
IMPU=YYY
MSISDN=ZZZ
IMSI=PPP
assocId=2
IMPI=ddd
IMPI=eee
IMPU=fff
IMPU=ggg
IMSI=hhh
IMSI=iii
MSISDN=jjj
MSISDN=kkk
assocId=3
IMPI=XXX
IMPU=YYY
MSISDN=ZZZ
IMSI=PPP
assocId=4
IMPI=ddd
IMPI=eee
IMPU=fff
IMPU=ggg
IMSI=hhh
IMSI=iii
MSISDN=jjj
MSISDN=kkk
```

I then wrote the following GAWK script:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
#
# Define the processing for a change of associd.
#
# NB: This function uses the GLOBAL variables:
#       IMPI
#       IMPU
#       IMSI
#       MSISDN
#
function new_assoc(assoc,     flag) {
        flag = 0
        if (IMPI > 1) flag=1
        if (IMPU > 1) flag=1
        if (IMSI > 1) flag=1
        if (MSISDN > 1) flag=1
        if (flag > 0) printf( "Found a multiple entry: %d\n", assoc )
        IMPI = IMPU = IMSI = MSISDN = 0
}
#
#       First thing, set up the field seperator.
#
BEGIN {
        FS = "="
}
#
#       Every time we hit an assoc line handle the previous one and then
#       initialise.
#
/^assocId/ {
        new_assoc( assoc )
        assoc = $2
}
#
#       Total up the four entries:
#
/^IMPI/   { IMPI++   }
/^IMPU/   { IMPU++   }
/^IMSI/   { IMSI++   }
/^MSISDN/ { MSISDN++ }
#
#       Ensure we process the last assoc on EOF:
#
END {
        new_assoc( assoc )
}
```

and when I ran it:

```
$ ./scan_it <src
Found a multiple entry: 2
Found a multiple entry: 4
```

Which I hope will act as a basis for what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

The following `awk` program will output the `assocId` IDs of any record containing duplicate keys. The code is logically much the same as [the code in Martin's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/714022/116858), but looks for duplication of *any* key within a record.

```c
BEGIN { FS = "=" }

function validate() {
    # Outputs a message if any key in "keys" is associated
    # with a number greater than 1.

    for (key in keys)
        if (keys[key] > 1) {
            printf "Check assocId=%s\n", id
            break
        }
}

/^assocId=/ {
    # New record.
    # Validate the previous record and delete the count of keys.
    validate()
    id = $2
    delete keys
}

{
    # Increment the counter for this key.
    keys[$1]++
}

END {
    # Validate the last record.
    validate()
}
```

As an unreadable one-liner:

```bash
awk -F = 'function v(){for(k in c)if(c[k]>1){printf "Check assocId=%s\n",id;break}}/^assocId=/{v();id=$2;delete c}{c[$1]++}END{v()}'
```

Running this on [the same test data as used by Martin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/714022/116858), you'll get the following output:

```
Check assocId=2
Check assocId=4
```

Comment: OP asked "I want to list all those occurrences of assocId with multiple IMPI, IMPU, IMSI and MSISDN attached.", not with any key, hence the explicit tests.

Comment: @Martin Yes, but the data that they show contains no other keys and they don't mention other keys. If the do have other keys then this solution is obviously crap. On the other hand, it's easy to insert a test for the incrementing block, just using e.g. `$1 ~ /^(IMPI|IMPU|IMSI|MSISDN)$/ { keys[$1]++ }`, so it's not like it's difficult to adapt.

Comment: That would be better, it also gets around the issue of blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to previous solutions.

```
function count() {
    if (impi > 1) {
        print associd, "with impi repeated ", impi, "times"
    }
    
    if (impu > 1) {
        print associd, "with impu repeated ", impu, "times"
    }

    if (msisdn > 1) {
        print associd, "with msisdn repeated ", msisdn, "times"
    }
}

/assocId/ {
    count()
    impi = 0
    impu = 0
    msisdn = 0
    associd = $0
}

/IMPI/ {
    impi += 1
}

/IMPU/ {
    impu += 1
}

/MSISDN/ {
    msisdn += 1
}

END {
    count()
}
```

```
assocId=2 with impi repeated  2 times
assocId=2 with impu repeated  2 times
assocId=2 with msisdn repeated  2 times
assocId=4 with impi repeated  2 times
assocId=4 with impu repeated  2 times
assocId=4 with msisdn repeated  2 times
```

I wish there was a way to call `count` only once, though.